# How to allow access to page variant (Page Manager) if user belongs to list

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

### The Situation

I have an ECK entity called "Event" in my Drupal 7 site.
I have an entity reference field on Event that collects users who flag the Event with a non-global flag called "Sign up" via a rule.
I use Page Manager to control how an Event entity is shown to the users.

My context:
**Edit relationship "User from Event (on Event: List of attendees [field_attendees]"**
`Event: Entity being viewed`
`Identifier: User from Event Attendees [field_attendees])`
`Keyword: event_attendees`
`Delta: 0`

Here is the Selection Rule:
`User: compare    logged_in_user is User from Event Attendees [field_attendees]`

### The Problem

As you can see, one of my Page Variants has a selection rule that checks if the logged_in_user is on the list of attendees but it doesn't work because the selection rule takes a "delta" and that means that it takes a ***hard coded*** integer to select one of the list. And if I leave this empty, it automatically takes "0" i.e. the first one in the list. There seems to be no option to set the delta to include all or any.

### The Question

How can I create this selection rule to check if this user is 'on the list'?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using a selection rule that checks if the logged-in user has "flagged" the Event with a Signup. This works but checking if the logged-in user is on the list would be a waterproof solution.